# cannot resolve symbol '__builtin_va_start' Visual Studio linux remote debug

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, g++, remote-debugging

working on converting a C project to c++, this code works in a normal C++ project, but when I started remote debugging to speed up testing, I am no longer able to use the va_start macro

```
#include "Utilities.h"
#include <cstdarg>
#include <stdarg.h>
void Utilities::PrintLine(const char* text, ...)
    {
        char buffer[100];
        va_list args;         // resolved just fine
        va_start(text, args); // cannot resolve
        vsprintf(buffer, text, args);
        va_end(args);         // cannot resolve
        std::cout << buffer << "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognise your use of [va_start](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) . The following will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

void PrintLine(const char* fmt, ...)
{
   char buffer[100];
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, fmt);
   vsprintf(buffer, fmt, args);
   va_end(args);
   std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}

PrintLine ("var arg %d %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: this does not work due to the same error. for some reason the compiler does not have a va_start defined which is strange because it should.

Comment: Runs fine for me in Visual Studio 2015 Pro Update 3, both natively on Windows 10 and via VC_Linux extension (1.0.5) on Mageia 5 Linux with GCC 4.9.2. Windows build suggested I use `vsprintf_s` but otherwise exactly the same code and result. Default project types and standard libraries. Suggest you share the compiler output so we can see the error messages.

Comment: Just a thought; on Linux, GCC maps `va_start` to `__builtin_va_start` in header `stdarg.h`. But there are circumstances where this might not happen. Do any of these apply in your case? What compiler and debugging tools are you using and which system are you running them on?

Comment: I think I am missing something in the configuration of the standard libraries/ compiler. I'm using all the default settings of VC_linux, pretty much the only things I've done is install VC_Linux, configure the remote accessing to my linux VM, and copy over the usr/includes. I haven't touched any other settings. building machine is ubuntu64bit, and I'm honestly not even sure how to check which compiler is being used (sorry not much more helpful, this is my first time every doing cross-platform writing/building).

Comment: well the good news is that it builds now.. and I'm uttering these words through clenched teeth, I don't know why.

vs still shows the same error, but it's actually succeeding in the build process.

1 question about VS remote debugging. should I remove their standard includes, and replace them with the ones pulled off my build machine?

Comment: well turns out the successful build fails to run, fixed that issue and now back to square one, although this now look like there is a linker issue that's unrelated. still genuinely confused about the va_start issues, but I'm guessing it's from something that's improperly configured in intellisense, not an actual error.